# how to get data from modal bottom sheet in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I've making form screen.

[image]

process is

1. button click
2. bottom sheet shown
3. user type their name => ok button clicked
4. TEXT will be changed by user name

i wanna get data from modal bottom sheet widget
but don't know how

this is my 2nd process code

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context, scrollController) =>
            RequestNameScreen());
    
  },
...
```

how can i get 'name' from bottom sheet ??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What `showModalBottomSheet()` does internally is - it pushes a new route onto the stack. So you can get data from bottom sheet in the same way as you'd get data from a screen (route).

```
String username = "TEXT";

InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context, scrollController) =>
            RequestNameScreen()
    ).then((value){
      setState((){
        username = value;
      });
    });
    
  },
...
```

And when you `pop` the sheet (`RequestNameScreen()`) on ok button, you can pass the text provided by user like this.

```
Navigator.pop(context, "text from user");
```

Comment: Thank you    (15characters in length )